# Is it possible to use LCD (the 16 pins) without potentiometer?

Tags: lcd

look, I don't have any potentiometer lying around, and I don't have any variable resistor. 
So is it possible to instead use a fixed resistor for the LCD display ?

Comment: Use regular resistors like Majenko said. But if you want to get extra fancy, you could [use one of the PWM pins to set the contrast in software](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/114924/lcd-brightness-and-contrast-control-with-pwm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can use two resistors in series to be a "fixed value" potentiometer.

The "wiper" of the potentiometer is the junction between the two resistors.

I can't tell you what values to use, so you'll have to experiment. You want them to add up to somewhere in the tens of kilo-ohms though, ideally, though the value isn't that critical - it's the ratio between the two values that is of interest, and it's that which gives you your contrast setting.